# What is the " : " Operator in PHP and how can i use it?

Tags: php, wordpress

o, i am not a PHP Ultra Pro programmer but I have been using it for a while in my projects... Recently I have accepted to take part in a Wordpress Template for Blog project and, looking into Wordpress' documentation found this piece of code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

I have never seen that " : " operator in PHP and would like to know how does that work and how can i use it in my projects... It seems like a time saver for me, so if anybody could help, that would be great!

Also, I can understand that it powers a if statement, than a while inside that if, can't figure the_post(); though, is that a function?

Comment: See also [Colon operator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10054345) and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: I've never seen it used like that before but in my experience it is the start of an `else` block in a ternary expression such as `echo (is_string($string) ? $string : 'Not a string');` Based on the flow of that line of code I would say it is something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is used for alternative php syntax structures. It used for replacing bracets, more details you can find here:
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php